# How do I center an arrow vertically

Tags: diagrams, center

I want to put an arrow vertically centered to show a transition from a state top another. What I have is
[image: The arrow is showing on the bottom part, but I want it centered (vertically)]

```
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{img/1.1.PNG}$\longrightarrow$\includegraphics[scale=0.33]{img/1.2.PNG}
\end{center}
```

How can I do this? Any alternative arrangement that shows the idea I want to transmit is well recieved, even if it doesn't solve my question

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

You need to set images baseline on theirs  vertical center:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}    % <---

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.33, valign=m]{example-image-a}
    $\longrightarrow$
\includegraphics[scale=0.33, valign=m]{example-image-b}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @BrunoAndrades, you are welcome. BTW, you may consider to accept answer (by clicking on the check mark at top of answer).